# Best window based server

Tags: c#, mysql, windows, server

I am beginner in development and I want to know which is best and affordable window based server. After many research on Google, I didn't get any good answer.

Please suggest Me good and  affordable window based server for .net development.

Comment: Recommendations are explicitly off-topic.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you just want something to run code while you are developing or learning you can simply use visual studio (even the free edition) and it will run IIS express to host your projects. It's also easy to then publish to Azure or AWS both of which offer 1 years free hosting to get you started. Hope that helps

Comment: But azure is not cheaper. Will you recommend any other ?

Comment: For testing purposes you can go with something like somee, tho I'm not quite happy with performance there.

Comment: are you looking for production servers or do you just want something to use while you are learning?